# How could fixed-point be implemented?

Tags: implementation, numbers, fixed-point

Fixed point is essentially storing a number of units of a certain size instead of storing a significand and an exponent. However, if the units could be of any size, how big would the fixed-point units be in a typical `fixed` type of a programming language? C does not have fixed-point, so to use this one just stores an integer and divides by the number of units in a 1 to get the value, for example, one could store an angle as a `uint16_t x;` representing 65536ths of a turn, and call `sinpif(x*0x1p-15F)`. However, if a language were to implement proper fixed-point semantics, how could this be done? What would be a typical range and precision of the varying fixed-point types?

Answer (score 6):

Fixed-point is an integer with a statically-known decimal (or more generally, statically-known divisor). You can represent a fixed-point datatype as an "representation" integer type and "divisor" integer (kind of like a fixed-sized array, which is an "element" type and statically-known "length" integer). At runtime, the value is simply an integer, but the compiler uses the statically-known divisor to do proper conversion (e.g. to floating-point or string).

For example, imagine a language with this syntax

```
type Currency = FixedPoint<u32, 100>

let currency1: Currency = 50.34  # represented as 5034
let currency2: Currency = 123.9  # represented as 12390
let currency3: Currency = currency1 + currency2  # represented as 17424
print(currency3)  # prints 174.24
```

Note that there isn't one "fixed-point" type, since different types may opt for different fixed points. The key difference between these types and a floating-point type, is that all instances of a particular fixed point type have the same "decimal" or divisor (whereas floating-points the decimal can be at different points at runtime).

---

I actually don't know any real-world languages which implement this feature, though. The closest may be F#, which has [measurement types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/units-of-measure). For your specific example, you could declare a `[<Measure>] type angle`, and then ensure that `int16<angle> n` is treated as `n 2*pi/65536` radians like so:

```
[<Measure>] type angle

let toRadians (x: int16<angle>) = x * 2 * pi / 65536<angle>
```

Then you can't use `int16<angle>` wherever a unit type is expected, you must apply `toRadians` first.

Comment: For real-world uses of fixed-point arithmetic, a good place to look is probably assembly languages for digital signal processing chips. Fixed point numbers are used a lot in DSP.

Comment: COBOL has fixed-point arithmetic. The reason some programmers care about fixed-point arithmetic is that it's used in the real world!

Answer (score 5):

## Make precision part of the type

I’m not familiar with any general-purpose languages that use fixed point at all, but this is what PostgreSQL does. If you want to indicate that a column stores 15 digits, of which two are to the right of the decimal point, type it as `NUMERIC(15, 2)`. This way, each user can choose a reasonable scale for their application, instead of the language forcing one on them.

Answer (score 3):

## Have a default precision, and allow changing it

Lisp has several different types of floats. One is `long-float`, with arbritrary precision. For example:

```clisp
(SETF (EXT:LONG-FLOAT-DIGITS) 3322)
```

This sets the "long float" precision to 3322 binary digits (approximately 1000 decimal digits). By default, it's 64 binary digits.

After this, you can print out a long float to see that it works: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18j2DXETUHDNSLEysffz13XzcffMUTXxdPdMyRYU8HY2MhIk0sjLb8oN7FEoURBqc5NSUFDX8HQx0DBXFPz/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## GCC Fixed-Point Types

[GCC has fixed point types as an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Fixed-Point.html). The types are `_Fract` and `_Accum` (A new language would designate them as just `fract` and `accum`) and could be combined with `long` `short` etc to specify precision, and `unsigned` to specify signedness.

### `fract`

A `fract` would store a normalized value between `[0, 1)`. The increments would be `1/2^bits` where `bits` is bits of precision. If signed, one of the bits would be a sign bit so the increments would be twice as big.

### `accum`

An `accum` would store half the bits as integer bits and half as fraction bits. The range would be `[0, 2^(bits/2))` but in increments of `1/2^(bits/2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Ada has fixed-point numbers: https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-5-9.html

The given examples are

```
type Volt is delta 0.125 range 0.0 .. 255.0;

  -- A pure fraction which requires all the available
  -- space in a word can be declared as the type Fraction:
type Fraction is delta System.Fine_Delta range -1.0 .. 1.0;
  -- Fraction'Last = 1.0 – System.Fine_Delta

type Money is delta 0.01 digits 15;  -- decimal fixed point
subtype Salary is Money digits 10;
  -- Money'Last = 10.0**13 – 0.01, Salary'Last = 10.0**8 – 0.01
```

There's two alternatives; a normal fixed-point type uses a power of two as its delta, and a decimal fixed-point type uses a power of ten.

Comment: The question is not what languages have fixed point but how you might implement it for your own language

Comment: @mousetail This shows the same details as the Lisp and SQL examples above. They're all examples of how the syntax could work, and certainly for binary fixed-point, the implementations pretty trivial; shift everything by the appropriate power of two on literals and conversions, don't worry about add and subtract, and do the obvious modifications on multiply and divide.